# How to auto purge old unapproved comments?

Tags: 7, comments, advertising, workbench

I would like to know if there is any way to automatically purge old unapproved comments on cron run.

The requirement is -- I have turned on email notification on new comments. I would like to approve only the genuine comments and leave the rest for auto-delete on passing certain time.

Of course I already have mollom, captcha and http:BL to fight spam.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if there is a module which does that. However, you could do that with the help of some custom coding inside `hook_cron`:

```
function MODULE_cron() {
  // Find out the comment ids of the comments that are unpublished
  // and are older than 30 days.
  $comments = db_query('SELECT cid FROM {comment} WHERE status = :status AND created < :created', array(':status' => 1, ':created' => strtotime('today - 30days')))->fetchAll();
  $cids = array();
  foreach($comments as $comment) {
    $cids[] = $comment->cid;
  }
  comment_delete_multiple($cids);
}
```

You can change the time to fit your requirements. This will ensure that on cron run the comments which are older than 30 days and are still unpublished get deleted.

Comment: Sure will do! Thanks for the code snippet. In fact this is what I had thought before posting this question. Want to check if any contrib module is already there as not to duplicate the effort.

Comment: BTW, to make the code even better. The SQL query could have "ORDER by created ASC" and db_query can be replaced with db_query_range($query, 0, 200); to delete the oldest first.

Comment: @AjitS: Shouldn't it be created < :created if you want the comments posted *before* the specified creation date.

Comment: @wimvds Good catch! Answer edited.

Comment: I needed that for Drupal 6, so ported and wrapped it into a D6 module: https://gist.github.com/amr/cc76bbfbac380996965f